# os.system('cls') randomly "jamming" cmd console screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, crash

Here is an image of what happens when you run it though python shell:

[image: screenshot of what happens when you run it though python shell]

So basically after 50 to 100+ turns my game will crash. It looks like the `os.system()` is not shutting down properly as it clears the screen. Using the python shell I can easily manually shut down the `cmd` page and continue with the game with no issues but when you run the game as an exe file or though console then that is not an option and hence crash the system.

I have tried putting a delay before the `os.system()` clear instructions and used `try`/`except` but it has not been able to fix the issue.

```
def clear_screen():
    playerMap[y][x] = "@"
    time.sleep(.1)
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    displayMap(playerMap)
```

For example if you click W for movement and end up on a position of "." then `clear_screen` will activate.

```
    if movement == "W":
        y = y-1
        position = mapChoice[y][x]
        playerMap[y][x] = "@"

    if position == ".":
        clear_screen()
        intro1=random.choice(intro)
        print (intro1)
        print("which direction will you go ?")
```

every time a movement has been made it will activate the clear screen function  but every 100 so move the `os.system()` function will "jam" for no reason.

Comment: Making a large number  of `os.system('cls`)` calls is probably _not_ the problem IMO, so I strongly suspect the problem has some other cause.

Comment: If I don't get a solution, just going to re-write the whole game again but just be cautious of anything that might cause this bug. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the issue with replacing os.system('cls') with print("\033c", end=""). Got over 500 turns before getting bored. I don't think os.system("cls") was designed for use for such a repetitive usage on every turn, every attack, every action it is getting activated.